# Mysql add temporary column if data not found

Tags: mysql, database, join, subquery

I have these two tables in mysql database, Can a query be made like this that if there is no data find for the column *islike* in like_tbl auto make a temp column with value false.

Like there is no data for post_id = 3 in like_tbl so the result should be like this as I mentioned below.

post_tbl

| post_id | uid | fname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abc |
| 2 | 1 | abc |
| 3 | 1 | abc |

like_tbl

| likeid | uid | postid | islike |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | true |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | true |

This is the result I'm looking for:

| post_id | uid | fname | islike |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | abc | false |
| 2 | 2 | abc | true |
| 3 | 2 | abc | false |

Summary I am trying to make a query which will return all post_id and check in `like_tbl` that the specific user has liked the post or not. If the data is there for the specific post_id of uid in the `like_tbl` it will return `islike` column value true otherwise it will return false if no data is found there for that post_id of the specific uid.

I have try this but not helping,

```
select n.* , e.isLike 
from post_tbl n 
join like_tbl on e.post_id = n.post_id 
where n.uid = '2' 
order by post_id desc
```

New to mysql DB any help would be appreciated

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE(islike, 'false')`.

Comment: I have tried this but its not retuning all the data from post_tbl, It's only returning the data which is in like_tbl

Comment: *its not retuning all the data from post_tbl, It's only returning the data which is in like_tbl* Replace JOIN with LEFT JOIN as suggested above.

Comment: Edit sample data, change `1` with `11`, `111` and so on - i.e. remove excess values interference. The same with `'abc'`.

Comment: but I need all the data from post_tbl and for that post_id if the data of the specific user is not there I want to display false, Right now its working good but only one thing I want all the data from post_tbl. As I mentioned above inthe result I wanted table

Comment: already did, I think you misunderstood the question. Please read summary in my question your answer is almost there I believe

Comment: *already did, I think you misunderstood the question.* I cannot understand it at all. For example, `like_id = 1` means that the user `uid=2` likes the post `post_id=1`, but in output this post is marked as `islike=false`. Why? PS. src data fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51cc5fa4478b335a22c34456154178cb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using ifnull and left join

```
select n.* , ifnull(e.isLike , 'false')
from post_tbl n 
LEFT JOIN like_tbl e on e.postid = n.post_id 
    AND e.uid = n.uid

order by post_id DESC
```

Comment: I have tried this but its not returning all the rows in post_tbl, I need all the rows from post_tbl

Comment: not working, now its getting all the data from post_tbl which is good but not for a specific user. I need a query which will return all post_id and check in like_tbl that the specific user has liked the post or not. If the data is there for the specific post_id of uid inthe like_tbl it will return islike coloumn value true otherwise it will return false if no data is found there for that post_id of the specific uid in like_tbl

Comment: missed  condition for useer ...added .. answer updated

Comment: Will give all `false`. It seems that `post_tbl.uid` is the post author whereas `like_tbl.uid` is post reader/liker. So they MUST be different (if self-like not allowed).

Comment: in fact you have all uid 1 in post_tbl and in pos_like t table you have not  uid1